# dotnet.exe prints big amount of text before running

Tags: .net-core

When I run any dotnet command from console such as

dotnet --version, dotnet --info even dotnet run MyProgram.dll

I get a big amount of text which slow down running of my program

A part of this text (**command is dotnet --info**):

```
Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\zh-Hant\Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\zh-Hant\Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.resources.dll'
Processing native/culture for deps entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer, 2.2.105-rtm, cs/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer/2.2.105-rtm/cs/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
Detected a resource asset, will query dir/ietf-tag/resource base: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\cs asset: Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources
    Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\cs\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\cs\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll'
Processing native/culture for deps entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer, 2.2.105-rtm, de/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer/2.2.105-rtm/de/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
Detected a resource asset, will query dir/ietf-tag/resource base: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\de asset: Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources
    Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\de\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\de\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll'
Processing native/culture for deps entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer, 2.2.105-rtm, es/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer/2.2.105-rtm/es/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
Detected a resource asset, will query dir/ietf-tag/resource base: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\es asset: Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources
    Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\es\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\es\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll'
Processing native/culture for deps entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer, 2.2.105-rtm, fr/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer/2.2.105-rtm/fr/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
Detected a resource asset, will query dir/ietf-tag/resource base: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\fr asset: Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources
    Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\fr\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\fr\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll'
Processing native/culture for deps entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer, 2.2.105-rtm, it/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer/2.2.105-rtm/it/Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll], probe dir [], probe fx level:0, entry fx level:0
Detected a resource asset, will query dir/ietf-tag/resource base: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\it asset: Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources
    Local path query exists C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\it\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll
    Probed deps dir and matched 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\it\Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.resources.dll'
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/W2wgCBFv

How can I skip displaying this text?

Comment: I don't have this, but I have .net core 3.1 installed. Have you tried to install .net core 3?

Comment: Same, I don't have this with .net core 3.1. It's like a debugger output. Where do you execute the command and where this text is displayed? In Visual Studio Prompt Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asnwer was in variable 'COREHOST_TRACE'. Its value was 1. Should be 0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you went though lot of installation/uninstall of different versions of dotnet core. Try to clean this up as dotnet run time seems to be lost when it is about loading assemblies of the framework (that's what all your messages are about).

What I would do at your place is that I would uninstall every version of dotnet core. Ensure that the path doesn't contain anything related to what you removed. And then install the dotnet core that you need.

FYI, the run time you launch is trying to use the RTM version of dotnet core 2.2. If you don't want to bother migrating to dotnet core 3.X, at least switch to the release version of 2.2 after cleaning every previous version that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Use -vm (minimal info) or -vq (quiet) switches like below:

```
dotnet -vm run MyProgram.dll
```

See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21